# How to get li with a span text inside

Tags: java, selenium

I want to catch an li with inside there is a span with text :

```
<li>
<span>Text here</span>
</li>
```

I tried to do this with XPath : `//span[text()="Text here"]/preceding::li` but does not work

Comment: Here is a list of axes : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this - `//span[text()="Text here"]/parent::li`